# heatmap.js - plotting multiple data points from .csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, heatmap, d3heatmap

I am trying to plot x1,y1 co-ordinates using heatmap.js, I read the values from .csv file using d3.csv() method. I tried with example in https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/, Got only one point plotted, but there are seven points in the .csv file.
Below is the code.

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function point()
{
alert("alert");
var points = []; 
var heatmap = h337.create({
  container: domElement
});

d3.csv("files/trial5.csv", function(error,data) {

   data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x1 = +d.x1;
    d.y1 = +d.y1;
    console.log("data : " +data + " " + error);
       heatmap.setData({
              max: 5,
              data:[{ x: d.x1, y: d.y1, value: 5}]

            }); 
       console.log("x:" + d.x1, "y:" + d.y1);

    }) 
  });


 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="domElement" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px; border: solid;"></div>                        
<input type="button" value="Click" id="clickButton" onclick="point()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `heatmap.setData` to outside your `forEach`:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x1 = +d.x1;
    d.y1 = +d.y1;
});

heatmap.setData({
    max: maxValue,//your max here
    min: minValue,//your min here
    data: data//your data array
});
```

Comment: I get a reference error when I move 'heatmap.setData'  outside 'forEach'. Reference error : d is not defined

Comment: Are you using the  `data` array, as I did? It's not just moving it, I changed the value of the `data` key.

Comment: I pass d.x1, d.y1 as x and y values : 

  d3.csv("files/trial5.csv", function(error, data) {

   data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x1 = +d.x1;
    d.y1 = +d.y1;
   });
   heatmap.setData({
    max : 5,
    data : [ {
     x : d.x1,
     y : d.y1,
     value : 5
    } ]
   });

Comment: No, you have to pass the data array, just as I did. That `d` only makes sense inside a function.

Comment: I pass the data array as below, I do not get any output or errors , just a blank screen .. Sorry for the confusion or my misunderstanding.. I am new to d3 and just picking things up..                                heatmap.setData({
    max : 5,
    data : data
    
   });

Comment: I do not get any errors nor the heatmap is plotted when I do the above. Kindly help

Comment: @sagar at this point, the best idea is creating a plunker with your actual CSV file and a working code. That way we can try to help you.